# python text parsing and splitting

Tags: python, parsing, text, split

I grab text file, as follows, from a web page using python. The data I grab includes extra things that I don't need. I only need parts that are bolded. I also need to split each of the bolded parts from each other. Would you help me to do so.In an image, also the red parts are what I am trying to extract from the data.

```
[
  '\n249\nSRUS54 KFWD 051849\nRR5FWD\n:\n: 
  ALERT HOURLY ACCUMULATOR DATA\n: 
  NATIONAL WEATHER SERVICE FORT WORTH TX\n:
  **1249 PM CST SUN MAR 5 2017**\n:\n: 
  HOURLY ACCUMULATOR INFORMATION TABLE\n:\n: 
  NOTE:  ERRONEOU        S REPORTS MAY BE RECEIVED UNDER CERTAIN\n:
          WEATHER CONDITIONS\n:\n:
 **********************************************************\n:
 ID    LOCATION                  ACCUMULATOR VALUE\n:
 **********************************************************\n:
 **CITY OF DALLAS ALERT SYSTEM**
 \n**.A DCQT2 170305 C DH124216 /HGIRS 
 396.7**:
 \n\n**.A DCVT2 170305 C DH123434 /HGIRS 516.8**:
 \n\n**.A DAOT2 170305 C DH123721 /HGIRS 534.2**:\n\n**.A DDCT2 
 170305 C DH120338 /HGIRS 395.0**:\n\n**.A DAHT2 170305 C DH114758 /HGIRS 
 496.1**:\n\n\n\n']
```

[This is an image of the data I grab from the web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7hVz.png)

```
import urllib
import re
htmlfile=urllib.urlopen("http://forecast.weather.gov/product.php?site=NWS&issuedby=FWD&product=RR5&format=CI&version=1&glossary=0")
htmltext=htmlfile.read()
regex='<pre class="glossaryProduct">(.+?)</pre>'
pattern=re.compile(regex,re.S)
out=re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
text=str(out)
saveFile=open('test.txt', 'w')
saveFile.write(text)
saveFile.close()
print (text)
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have written. Also it will be good if you provide the example with good formatting.

Comment: import urllib
import re
htmlfile=urllib.urlopen("http://forecast.weather.gov/product.php?site=NWS&issuedby=FWD&product=RR5&format=CI&version=1&glossary=0")
htmltext=htmlfile.read()
regex='<pre class="glossaryProduct">(.+?)</pre>'
pattern=re.compile(regex,re.S)
out=re.findall(pattern, htmltext)
text=str(out)
saveFile=open('test.txt', 'w')
saveFile.write(text)
saveFile.close()
print (text)

Comment: Format the list output as well.

Comment: I added an image of the data I grab from the web, does it help?

Comment: try BeautifulSoup library to extract the data. It is more structured. Also  I do not see any this in bold in image you provided. I think you should once refer "How to ask questions" section in SO.

Comment: I added another image in which the parts I need are in red boxes. I tried BeautifulSoup, but it grabs all the html of the page. Am I right?

Comment: Your regex has got nothing to do with the target text. Nothing at all. Is that your question? The regex?

Comment: Really!!? I didn't know that. BTW, my question is how to grab the data from the web in a manner that I can parse it, and I am not sure how to parse and split it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOAA data is usually formatted pretty regularly. The best approach is to split the input into separate lines and then loop through line-by-line.

Skip lines, unless they start with a phrase or keyword you're interested in. For example:

```
for line in text.split('\n'):
    if any([re.match('^: [0-9]{4} [AP]M', line),   # matches : 1249 PM
            line.startswith(': CITY OF'),          # CITY OF...
            line.startswith('.A D')]):             # .A D....
    saveFile.write(line)
```

(You'll need to modify the above base on what the actual, possible line values are.)

Answer (score 1):

In python3 you could try following:

```
import urllib.request
import re
htmlfile=urllib.request.urlopen("http://forecast.weather.gov/product.php?site=NWS&issuedby=FWD&product=RR5&format=CI&version=1&glossary=0")
htmltext=htmlfile.read()
regex='<pre class="glossaryProduct">(.+?)</pre>'
pattern=re.compile(regex,re.S)
out=re.findall(pattern, htmltext.decode())

print("7'th line:", out[0].split('\n')[7])
print(out[0].split('\n')[17])

# print all the lines
for line in out[0].split('\n'):
    print(line)
```

Comment: Thank you! It is so helpful. As far as the number of lines differs time to time, can I adjust this code to go over all the lines? For example, now 5 lines are reported in the page, but the next report may contain 10 lines and I need all of them.

Comment: Sorry I have missed your question. I have added how to in the main answer.